# changing the size of the navigation drawer icon

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, navigation-drawer

i am currently working on the navigation drawer.i have correctly made the navigation drawer but i want to change the size of the navigation drawer icon.i had chnaged the size of the text and color but unable to change the size of the icon

here is my navigation_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

>

<item android:id="@+id/Home"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_home_black_24dp"
    android:title="home"

/>

<item android:id="@+id/Events"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_event_black_24dp"
    android:title="Events"/>

<item android:id="@+id/Mail"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_event_black_24dp"
    android:title="Mail"/>

<item android:id="@+id/Shop"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_shop_black_24dp"
    android:title="Shop"/>

<item android:id="@+id/Travel"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_card_travel_black_24dp"
    android:title="Travel"/>
```

and here is my styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item 
name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_material_light</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="NavDrawerTextStyle" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:smallIcon">@mipmap/ic_event_black_24dp</item>
</style>
```

can anybody tell me how to change the size of the navigation drawer icon????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the size of image you want to set. (Default is 24x24 dp) I generated a vector image using the Vector asset feature of Android Studio. (Image is known as 'dehaze' or 'menu' in Icon list)

Steps I followed:

1. Generated a vector image of 48x48 dp (named it ic_navigation_icon)
2. Added the below lines to my onCreate of the activity. You will already have the first two lines of the below snippet in your code. Add the remaining part.

   ```
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


   if(getSupportActionBar()!=null)
       {
           Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_navigation_icon);
           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
           getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);

       }
   ```
3. Then I had to comment the syncState() method of ActionBarDrawerToggle that I was calling. (This method is used to convert the navigation icon to a left arrow when the navigation drawer is in open state.) Since my navigation drawer is over the action bar, I did not need to use this method.

   Comment this line if there is, else your customized icon will not be seen

   //toggle.syncState();

I hope this helps!